# First blank ("") cell in column with IF formula

Tags: vba, excel, nonblank

I have a macro that exactly copies one sheet's data into another.

```
Sub QuickViewRegMgmt()

    ("Reg Management").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Quick View Reg Mgmt").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I would like for this macro to also go to the last non-blank cell in Column C (or first blank, I really don't care either way). I tried simple end/offset code, e.g.

```
Range("A1").End(xldown).Offset(1,0).Select
```

My problem, however, is that the direct copy macro also copies the underlying formulas, which for Column C is an IF formula. Therefore, no cell in the column is actually empty, but rather they all have an IF formula resulting in a true/false value (respectively, a "" or VLOOKUP).

```
=IF(VLOOKUP('Reg Management'!$Y260,'Reg Guidance'!$A:$V,3,FALSE)=0,"",VLOOKUP('Reg Management'!$Y260,'Reg Guidance'!$A:$V,3,FALSE))
```

That means the end/offset code goes to the last cell in the column with the formula (C1000) instead of going to the first cell that has a value of "" (which is currently C260).

What code can I add to this macro to select the first cell that contains an IF formula resulting in a value of "" ---- which has the appearance of being blank?

Comment: `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` ? or maybe `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`..

Comment: you could use `Range.Find` to get the first cell with `""` in a set range like `Columns(1)`

Comment: @DirkReichel - How? I keep trying that, but it skips the `=""` rows and goes to the first literally empty cell.

Comment: @BruceWayne Were you looking in `xlValues` or `xlFormulas`?  (e.g. `Columns(3).Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)` should work - it does for me.)

Comment: @YowE3K - ...Well, I didn't specify, so I suppose it was `xlValues`. Let me revisit what I was trying and report back. I'd like to make my answer better, and not just loop through cells.  In my mind this could be a two-liner at most.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to be fancy with `SpecialCells()`, or using `Find()` or something I couldn't get it ...so here's a rather "dirty" way to do it:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow As Long, lastFormulaRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long
For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Formula <> "" And Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
        lastFormulaRow = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Edit2:  Here's one using `.SpecialCells()`. Granted I *think* we can whittle this down more, I like it better:

```
Sub lastRow()
Dim tempLastRow As Long
tempLastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

Dim lastRow As Range
Set lastRow = Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, after:=Range("C" & tempLastRow))
Debug.Print lastRow.Row
End Sub
```

[image]

It returns `10` as the row.

Edit: **Be sure** to add the sheet references before `Range()` and `Cells()` to get the last row. Otherwise, it's going to look at your active sheet to get the info.